# Amazon ec2 public ip can't access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I previously haven't worked with amazon web services and haven't had very big experience with servers so I don't know what's wrong.

There is ruby on rails app deployed on ec2 instance. When I want to open app with public ip it shows only the content of `public` folder of the rails app

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing your apache or nginx server to the public directory of your rails app.

You should point it to the root of the rails app if for example you are using the [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) module in combination with the appropriate config for the module.

Can you post your configs for nginx or apache?

Comment: I have apache as a server for ec2 instance. What do you mean by configs?

Comment: Your default apache config. On CentOS it would be in something like `/etc/httpd/conf.d` and on ubuntu something like `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: Yes it was pointing to the wrong folder. I updated the config and now everything works fine